# Auto-Import of WXR File

Tags: uploads, automation, bulk-import

I am running a WPMU instance and need to import around 1200 sites at once. I have put a process in place to create a properly formatted WXR file for each one. What I am missing at this point is how to access the WP Import option without the GUI, so I can automate this import. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress Importer Extended](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-importer-extended/) is the plugin that you are looking for.

Comment: This isn't a valid option for me; I would have to network activate the plugin, which would then kick off about 1200 (sizeable) data download/uploads. Thanks tho.

If I am able to access the import procedure automatically, I can effectively schedule it, as well as control how the media is uploaded along with the posts.